# Bounding the second moment of $|\zeta(\sigma+i t)|^2$ for $0<\sigma<1$

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

Let
$$I(\sigma,T)=\int_0^T |\zeta(\sigma+ i t)|^2 dt.$$
Unconditional bounds and asymptotics for $I(\sigma,T)$, $1/2\leq \sigma <1$, have been known since Hardy and Littlewood (see Chapter 7 of Titchmarsh). What about $0<\sigma<1/2$?

One can of course use the functional equation to try to obtain something useful. I am interested in whether there are results in the literature I can reference (there have to be!). In particular, I would like to see an unconditional result with the right constant in front of the main term.

(The main term should be of the form $c_\sigma T^{2-2\sigma}$, $c_\sigma$ a constant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ingham has a nice discussion of this in the introduction of his 1926  [paper.](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1575391)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, now that it's solved, is there anything explicit in the literature?

Comment: By explicit, if you mean explicit bounds instead of those with implicit constants, then I don't know.